# how to set default number keyboard in edittext

Tags: android, keyboard, textview

using EditText i want to use phone keyboard (with letters) by default(!), but using

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

android disables letters input when i change keyboard softly. and i'm also need to use letters when it need
how should i declare inputType or something else to use phone keyboard by default and don't lose letters input ability?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I did not understand what you are trying to tell

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

You can use two type of inputTypes: Must be one or more (separated by '|') of the following constant values.

So, you should use something like: android:inputType="phone|text"

[]s
Neto